# Comparing strings alphabetically in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, alphabetical

I'm writing the compare function that will get passed to a qsort, and I'm having trouble getting the string to sort alphabetically.

```
typedef struct{
    char title[30];
    //other irrelevant variables
} Album;

compare(Album * l, Album * r){

    if(l->title > r->title){
         return -1;
    }
    if(l->title == r->title){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}

qsort(albums, num_albums, sizeof(Album), compare);
```

I know this is probably wrong, but I'm not sure how to compare to char pointers alphabetically. Can someone help this old chap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bare array name evaluates to the address of the first array element. You need to compare the string contents, not the string addresses. There happens to be a nice function to do that—[`strcmp`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strcmp.htm):

```
compare(Album * l, Album * r) {
    return strcmp(l->title, r->title);
}
```

Comment: so simple, yet effective. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

First, your `compare` function does not have a return type indicated.  I'll assume it's supposed to return `int`.

When you compare `l->title` and `r->title` using the `>` and `==` operators, what is really happening is that pointers to memory locations are being compared, not actual characters.  The variable `l->title` is really a pointer to the first element of the (character) array that `l->title` logically represents.

You are looking for the function `strcmp` (Google for it or type `man strcmp` in a *nix terminal).  If you want to write it from scratch you will need to write a function that compares the strings one character at a time.  For example `l->title[0]` is the first character of that string, `l->title[1]` is the second, etc.

Answer (score 0):

strcmp performs binary sorting not alphabetical sorting. For example "RT" would come before "Re". Beware of strings with mixed upper and lower case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).